# how to access a command prompt on one computer from another using linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I'm looking to virtualize a home computer running ubuntu server. I want to run python scripts on my home computer from my laptop. I have no idea how to configure that. I figure I need to configure an ubuntu server on my home desktop so that I can access its command prompt from my laptop. how would I install and configure ubuntu server to do that? How would I access the server from my laptop?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. This question is probably more appropriate for askubuntu.com.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really specific to ubuntu, it's the same for any linux/unix platform

You should run ssh-server on the server (your home computer)

then

```
$ ssh <the-server> <path-to-python-script>
```

will run the script on the server.

You can also just get a console on the server like this

```
$ ssh <the-server>
```

and then run whichever commands you like